# Encoding, datatypes & packed repeated fields

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have some questions regarding packed fields, and storing/serializing
data with protocolbuffers.
What i want to do essentially, is to store 4MB of data to a file.

The data i have (in our embedded system) is received as uint8_t (a byte) and i want to store this data as efficiently as possible.

I have been testing a variety of protobuf setups (four);

```
repeated uint32_t datastruct = 1;
repeated uint32_t datastruct = 1 [packed = true]
```

with both variants assigned 1-to-1 (putting a uint8 to uint32) and both variants bitshifted with 4 values cramped into a uint32_t.

To my surprise the stored files are much larger than the original
data. (the examples where i put a uint8 into uint32 was expected of course..)
The best result i could achieve was 5.2MB for the 4MB data, which
really isnt that good.

Have i misunderstood something vital here?
I do realize that protobuf adds information to the packets, but 25%
increase is too much imho.

Also using GzipOutputStream increases the size of the file instead of decreasing it.

Any tips would be very appreciated!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is `uint32_t` here? is that a `message` in .proto?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case.

Comment: then... I'm confused... I didn't think "packed" even *worked* for such...? or is it a group?

Comment: To quote from the documentation: `Only repeated fields of primitive numeric types (types which use the varint, 32-bit, or 64-bit wire types) can be declared "packed".` - to the best of my knowledge, if `uint32_t` is a `message`, it is **invalid** to use "packed"

Comment: I realize i was i bit unclear here, in the protofile the following is defined: repeated uint32 datafield  = 1 [packed = true]; The datatypes i use in conjuction with this message is of type uint32_t (and of course 32 bits).

Comment: ah, right; that makes more sense then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that you are using `uint32` in .proto terms:

`packed` is a positive thing here (removes headers per value); however, by packing a single uint8 into a uint32, you are running into a facet of "varint" encoding - specifically, that if the most significant bit of the byte is set, it will take 2 bytes (varint uses 7 bits per byte for data, and one bit as *continuation*). Consequently, I would recommend switching to the `bytes` type, which represents any arbitrary chunk of bytes, and is encoded "as is", without any varint or similar. It wouldn't be repeated/packed - just:

```
[required|optional] bytes data = 1;
```

Another option would be to use `fixed32` (repeated and packed), and place (via shifting) 4 bytes per value, but by the time you've done that you may as well go to `bytes` and have a more obvious 1:1 map.

Re gzip; it is not uncommon for gzip to increase the size of arbitrary binary without many repeated blocks. By contrast, if your protobuf document contains strings it is common for the size to shrink, as gzip can spot repeated blocks.

Comment: 7 bits for data and one bit as continuation.

Comment: Upon testing with the bytes datatype, the space consumed was marginally more than the incoming data. Wrt gzip'ing the space consumed by the protobuf message decreased drastically once patterns emerged in the data.

Comment: @almagest yes, as per my comment on Mike's answer, there is a 5 byte overhead for storing a 4MB blob as field 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a sequence of bytes, use the `bytes` datatype. The overhead will be tiny.

The extra overhead you're seeing from `int32` comes from the variable-length coding; numbers are stored with 7 bits in each byte, and the 8th indicates whether there is more. So a full-scale 32 bit value will need 5 bytes to store. There is a `fixed32` type, which always takes 32 bits (4 bytes) per value - that will be more efficient if most values need 32 bits to represent, and less efficient if most values are small.

Comment: specifically, the overhead (for field #1, as illustrated) will be 1 byte for the header and 4 bytes to represent the length of 4MB as "varint"